# Building Xcode project with Jenkins gives codesign error

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, unity-game-engine, jenkins

I'm trying to build Xcode project with Jenkins. Project for Xcode generated by Unity Engine.
I am able to build this project directly from Xcode GUI, but when trying to build project through Jenkins i'm getting following error at the end of build:

```
Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: MyName MySurname (XXXXXXXXXX)"
Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *"
                      (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX)

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 37DF6AF254E5A4856B1BA024D199DEE3CE596A58 --entitlements /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Xcode_Input/build/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/myapplication.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Xcode_Input/build/Release-iphoneos/myapplication.app
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Xcode_Input/build/Release-iphoneos/myapplication.app: errSecInternalComponent
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CodeSign /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Xcode_Input/build/Release-iphoneos/myapplication.app
(1 failure)
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried to reproduce following command in terminal, and it woked fine without any errors:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 37DF6AF254E5A4856B1BA024D199DEE3CE596A58 --entitlements /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Xcode_Input/build/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/myapplication.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Xcode_Input/build/Release-iphoneos/myapplication.app
```

It asked me for my password two times(and same password specified in Jenkins job settings for Xcode), and finished without any errors.

Keychain i used to sign project is unlocked with: `security unlock-keychain login.keychain`

The question is - what could be the reason of following behavior? How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Jenkins is SSHing into the box and not receiving access to your keychain. Jenkins needs to unlock the keychain before performing the build. It looks like you already understand how to unlock your keychain via password prompt. You need to have Jenkins perform the unlock without a prompt.

Have Jenkins run the following before your build command:

`security unlock-keychain -p <YourPassword> ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`

If you'd rather not store the password in cleartext script area of your build, Jenkins offers various ways to store secrets and retrieve them as variables. Here's a decent write-up on doing that: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs

Alternatively:

```
security unlock-keychain -p `cat ~/.file_with_your_password` ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```